# Show that the formula is satisfiable

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

The formula is: $$P(f(a),g(b))\to R(h(a,b,c))\lor P(f(a),g(b)))$$

Here, $a,b$ are constants, $P,R$ are relations and $f,g,h$ are functions.

Now, if we assume that $P(f(a),g(b)) = t$ then it's easy to easy that the formula is true, but how do I deal with the case where $P(f(a),g(b)) = f$?

Comment: What does it mean for $R$ to be a relation that takes only one argument?

Comment: a term can be in the relation or not. For example, $R$ could be the relation "isHuman".

Comment: The formula is equivalent to: $\lnot P \lor R \lor P$; thus it is clearly satisfiable: if $P(f(a),g(b))=$ **f**, then $\lnot P(f(a),g(b))=$ **t**.

Comment: Oh you right. Thank you @MauroALLEGRANZA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An implication $A \to B$ is equivalent to $\neg A \vee B$. Therefore, your forumla can be transformed to

$$\neg P(f(a),g(b)) \vee R(h(a,b,c)) \lor P(f(a),g(b))$$

The formula is always true, since $\neg P(f(a),g(b)) \vee P(f(a),g(b))$ is a tautology and true in all interpretations.